# Windows 10 MVC Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc' or one if it's depdencies. 0x80131040

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, windows-10

I installed Windows 10 on a 2 new VM's.  Installed Visual Studio 2013 with Update 5.  Got a solution which contains MVC web app which uses IIS.

Now on both VM's, the web app fails to load with The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference.

I've removed the assembly from NuGet and added it back, I've deleted the bin folder, just about everything I could find on the internet.

The redirect in the web.config appears to be correct,

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

The nuget version installed is 5.2.3  On windows 8 or Windows 7 machines, this isn't a problem.

Again, this is a brand new install and only Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate has been installed.

What's odd, if I go and create a new MVC web app, then it will load.

I've enabled Fusion and here are the logs.

```
Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = System.Web.Mvc
 (Partial)
WRN: Partial binding information was supplied for an assembly:
WRN: Assembly Name: System.Web.Mvc | Domain ID: 9
WRN: A partial bind occurs when only part of the assembly display name is provided.
WRN: This might result in the binder loading an incorrect assembly.
WRN: It is recommended to provide a fully specified textual identity for the assembly,
WRN: that consists of the simple name, version, culture, and public key token.
WRN: See whitepaper http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=109270 for more information and common solutions to this issue.
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/TFS/AppName/Trunk/SL.Main/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = C:\TFS\AppName\Trunk\SL.Main\bin
Calling assembly : (Unknown).
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\TFS\SLHV01\AppName\web.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet.config
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/slmain/64560d57/1f691ecd/System.Web.Mvc.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/slmain/64560d57/1f691ecd/System.Web.Mvc/System.Web.Mvc.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/AppName/bin/System.Web.Mvc.DLL.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\TFS\SLHV01\SmartLogix\SmartLynx\SmartLynx\UI\Trunk\SL.Main\web.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet.config
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Redirect found in application configuration file: 4.0.0.1 redirected to 5.2.3.0.
LOG: Post-policy reference: System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/slmain/64560d57/1f691ecd/System.Web.Mvc.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/slmain/64560d57/1f691ecd/System.Web.Mvc/System.Web.Mvc.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/TFS/AppName/bin/System.Web.Mvc.DLL.
WRN: Comparing the assembly name resulted in the mismatch: Major Version
ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x80131040). Probing terminated.
```

Stack Trace:

```
[FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)]

[FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)]
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +0
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +234
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection) +108
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection) +25
   System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString) +34
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +49

[ConfigurationErrorsException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)]
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +772
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAllAssembliesFromAppDomainBinDirectory() +256
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssembly(AssemblyInfo ai) +58
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection compConfig) +237
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetPreStartInitMethodsFromReferencedAssemblies() +101
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(String preStartInitListPath, Boolean& isRefAssemblyLoaded) +142
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart() +172
   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +907

[HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +579
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +112
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +726
```

Note replaced my directories with App name in the file paths.

Note there is no `System.Web.Mvc.dll` in the Temporary Asp.Net files, folders and I checked on my Windows 7 & Windows 8 VM's and it isn't there either.

Starting this thread to try and get input and hopefully help others.  With this happening with two installs, my guess this will probably happen to other as well.

I'm trying to figure where a mismatch would be coming from.

8/7/15 - After I figured out VS build was putting the incorrect version of MVC in the bin folder. (I had checked yesterday.)  If I by pass Visual Studio and just open the website directly in a browser so there is no build and the Bin folder is updated, then the site opens.

Now trying to figure out why if the reference to System.Web.Mvc is 5.2.3 and the nuget package matches, why the build is then putting a version 4 in the bin folder.

Comment: Did you verify that the assembly is in the bin folder?  Are you running under IIS or IIS Express?

Comment: Since a brand-new project works, you might want to use something like WinMerge to compare the solution and project files from your existing applications to the brand new versions.

Comment: This new solution is one project, the other is a large 27 project solution.  One thing I've noticed is the temp solution I created, I hosted it in IIS but there is no folder in the temporary Asp.Net Files folder.  Also, I've tried change the Web Server for the main project to IIS Express, still the same error.

Comment: Also, I tried deleting the package folder and then using NuGet to restore.  Nuget fails with a 404 error.  Wireshark shows a connection and then some reason a reset packet is sent.  Having to wipe all the files and get latest from TFS again.  Latest files that work in all other workstations.

Answer (score 0):

Correct dll is in bin folder.  I'm using iis.  One other thing is i used VS with update 5 on the windows 10 vms and other vms are Update 4.

Comment: Also, I tried deleting the package folder and then using NuGet to restore.  Nuget fails with a 404 error.  Wireshark shows a connection and then some reason a reset packet is sent.  Having to wipe all the files and get latest from TFS again.  Latest files that work in all other workstations.  Going back and rechecking everything, I looked in the bin folder and the version of the MVC file is 4.x.  Odd because it was 5x.  I copied the files out of the package folder into the bin and tried to debug again but the files are getting overwritten.  Even though the project reference shows 5.2.3

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where some of the follow ups I've posted here went.  Originally, checking the bin folder I could have sworn the correct dll was in the bin.  I had checked all our web projects to make sure they were using version 5.2.3.

The next day I started realizing the version in the bin folder was 4. But trying to figure out why MSBuild was copying the incorrect version to the in even though 5.2.3 was referenced and the project file was point to 5.2.3 for it's hint was puzzling.

I started a post in the VS forum and a person suggested build logging which alerted me to a none web help project which was referencing 4.0 of the dll.

Update the assemblies for that one project and it appears to have resolved the problem.  We haven't had this issue since Jan. on any other machines, but just started happening on fresh installs of W10 with VS 2013 Update 5.

Here is the other [thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a73e7b73-763d-422a-bb51-6393c36b6ae8/visual-studio-2013-ultimate-update-5-on-windows-10-pro-is-copying-wrong-dll-to-bin-folder?forum=msbuild&prof=required).